# Installing service fabric on windows 11

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I downloaded both service fabric runtime and sdk, however when trying to run the runtime.exe i get the following "Installation must be called with /accepteula. Running without arguments from explorer is not supported.
Press enter to exit. Process will automatically close after 30 seconds."

The i proceed to "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser" and in the powershell navigate to the folder that contains the two executable and run "MicrosoftServiceFabric.9.1.1653.9590.exe /force /accepteula", but the command is not recognized even though i added the path variables according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1181752/service-fabric-runtime-installation-for-windows-fa , can someone please assist, I'm running windows 11 OS

Comment: So in your powershell window when you run that, what is the exact error message? In a powershell window you usually need to prepend with .\ i.e. `.\MicrosoftServiceFabric.9.1.1653.9590.exe /force /accepteula`

Comment: Managed to sort it out, but ran with normal cmd not powershell, i navigated to the folder where i have service fabric runtime and typed the name of the executable

Comment: It's worth learning the .\ thing (in fact I beleive it puts the suggestion in the error message)